# Add class to parent div if it has a span as child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have number of filters to show products in my shop. I'm using bootstrap-select to style the filter (dropdowns).

When I change a filter value, the other filters automatically hide options if there are no results available for that combination.

The problem is, that there a re now Filters that show that don't have any available options to choose from. In this case I want to hide the Filter completely.

If there are options available the code looks like this:

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label>Serie</label>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control open"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-dropdown btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-serie" title="Bitte wählen..." aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="filter-option pull-left">Bitte wählen...</span>
  <span class="bs-caret">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </span>
  </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true">
        <li data-original-index="0"><a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="text">D-9</span><span class="fontawesome fa fa-check check-mark"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <label class="custom-select">
      <select id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-serie" name="wpv-wpcf-serie[]" class="selectpicker js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="D-9">D-9</option>
      </select>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there is no option available, the code looks like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Passend für Helm</label>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control open">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-dropdown btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch" title="Bitte wählen..." aria-expanded="true">
      <span class="filter-option pull-left">Bitte wählen...</span>
      <span class="bs-caret">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true"></ul>
    </div>
    <label class="custom-select">
      <select id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch" name="wpv-wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch[]" class="selectpicker js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-98">
      </select>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to add a class `.hide-filter` to `.form-group` if the child `.dropdown-menu` has no `li`

Comment: Hi! At this site, we require you to at least try to solve the problem yourself first. Try to solve this yourself and when you run into a problem, add your code as [mcve] and explain in detail what is not working as you intend.

Answer (score 1):

try below code where you can iterate each form-group and find if it contains dropdown with no li.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.form-group').each(function(){
     var $dropdown = $(this).find('.dropdown-menu');
     if($dropdown.find('li').length==0) {
        $(this).addClass('hide-filter');
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Passend für Helm</label>
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control open"><button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-dropdown btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch" title="Bitte wählen..." aria-expanded="true"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Bitte wählen...</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
    <div
      class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true"></ul>
  </div><label class="custom-select"><select id="wpv_control_select_wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch" name="wpv-wpcf-kompatibilitat-extern-mechanisch[]" class="selectpicker js-wpv-filter-trigger form-control" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-98"></select><span></span></label></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if($( ".dropdown-menu.inner:has(li)" ).length == 0){
      $( ".form-group" ).addClass( "hide-filter" );
    }
});
```